# Using Multiple user id - authentication with CAS 4.x

Tags: java, authentication, cas

My question is simple, is it possible to configure an authentication in order to use two different ID ?

I'm using database handler to authenticate users and I would like users have the opportunity to **log in with their email OR login**.

I'm reading the doc (i.e, http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.1.x/installation/Database-Authentication.html) but don't see an explicit way ... if you have any suggestion.

Thx.

J.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to construct a query that takes two fields and OR them together.